# How to manitain session values during HttpWebRequest?

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

In my `code` I'm sending a `HttpWebRequest` to a page in my website.

When `request` sends to this page, It doesn't maintain the `Session` values.

**Below is the code, from where I'm generating the web request:**

```
Public Overloads Shared Function ReadURL(ByVal sUrl As String) As String
        Dim sBody As String
        Dim oResponse As HttpWebResponse
        Dim oRequest As HttpWebRequest
        Dim oCookies As New CookieContainer
        oRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:64802/inventory/purchase_order.aspx?id=5654")
        oRequest.CookieContainer = oCookies
        oResponse = oRequest.GetResponse()
        Dim oReader As New StreamReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream())
        sBody = oReader.ReadToEnd
        oReader.Close()
        oResponse.Close()
        Return sBody
    End Function
```

**Below is the code written on Page_Load of Purchaseorder.aspx.vb:**

```
iDomains_ID = Session("Domains_ID")
        iLogin_ID = Session("Login_ID")
        sPage = Request.Path
        If Request.QueryString.Count > 0 Then sPage &= "?" & Request.QueryString.ToString()
        sPage = shared01.Encrypt(sPage, Application("PK"))

        If Not User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Or iLogin_ID = 0 Then
            Response.Redirect("/login.aspx?page=" & sPage)
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

Above `code` doesn't gets the `session` values and it redirects to the `login page`.

So, how i can maintain the `session` on both pages during `HttpWebRequest`.

Looking for your replies.

**EDIT**

I've tried to use `CookieContainer` class as you can see in above code. But it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, assuming the calling and called pages are in the same application, you could use [the `Server.Execute` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8e2dw5s.aspx) to load the content of the page without making a separate request to the site:

```
Public Overloads Function ReadURL(ByVal sUrl As String) As String
    Using writer As New StringWriter()
       Server.Execute("~/inventory/purchase_order.aspx?id=5654", writer, False)
       Return writer.ToString()
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Its working fine. :)  I hope i won't create any problem on server. What you think?

Comment: @CodeRider: This version will be less likely to cause problems than making a separate request to the site, since it will only use a single ASP.NET thread to process the request.

Comment: Thanks Richard. You helped me a lot. I'll mark it as answer after testing it on server.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, you're making a request from one page in your site to another, and you want to send the cookies from the current `HttpRequest` with your `WebRequest`?

In that case, you'll need to manually copy the cookies to the `CookieContainer`:

```
For Each key As String In Request.Cookies.AllKeys
   Dim sourceCookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies(key)

   Dim destCookie As New Cookie(sourceCookie.Name, sourceCookie.Value, sourceCookie.Path, "localhost")
   destCookie.Expires = sourceCookie.Expires
   destCookie.HttpOnly = sourceCookie.HttpOnly
   destCookie.Secure = sourceCookie.Secure

   oCookies.Add(destCookie)
Next
```

**NB**: You'll either need to make the `ReadUrl` function non-`Shared`, or pass the current `HttpRequest` as a parameter.

You'll also need to make sure the calling page has `EnableSessionState="false"` in the `<%@ Page ... %>` directive, otherwise the page you're calling will hang trying to obtain the session lock.

Comment: I just want to access session values on next page. Is it possible using `cookie container`?

Comment: @CodeRider: What do you mean by "not sending"? Is it making the request but not sending the cookies, or is there something else going wrong?

Comment: I mean to say that Its not making request any more.

Comment: @CodeRider: Is the site still running on the same port? That URL looks like you're running the site from Visual Studio.

Comment: yes, I'm working on localhost. It was making the web request to another page befor using the code you posted above. But now its not making any web request to another page.

Comment: @CodeRider: But is the site still running on port 64802? If you open [the URL](http://localhost:64802/inventory/purchase_order.aspx?id=5654) in your browser, does it work? And are you getting an exception from the web request code?

Comment: Yes, site is running on the same port. When i open the url in browser, it works fine. I'm getting some timeout exception on  `oResponse = oRequest.GetResponse()`

Comment: @CodeRider: The [default `Timeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx) is 100 seconds. If your page takes longer than that to load, you'll need to increase the value of the `Timeout` property on the request.

Comment: when i use normal code except you posted, It works fine and instantly hit the break point on another page. Any solution for this?

Comment: @CodeRider: According to your original question, when you don't send the cookies the request is redirected to the login page. If the "normal" code works fine, then what's the problem?

Comment: I mean to say that it works fine in terms of sending web request but it doesn't maintain session on another page. thats it.

Comment: @CodeRider: Then the request without the cookies isn't executing the same code as the request with the cookies. If the request with the cookies takes longer to execute, then you'll need to increase the timeout.

Comment: gettin this one : System.Net.CookieException: The 'Port'='64802' part of the cookie is invalid.

Comment: @CodeRider: OK, try taking the `destCookie.Port = ` line out again. You'll probably also need to disable the session state on the calling page.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems like you will need to make a request and a post. The first request will redirect you to your login page. The second will be a request where you post to the login page, which will start the session and (?) store information into the session variables. That post (to the login page) will then redirect you to the page you want.

I used code in this example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/145122/Fetching-ASP-NET-authenticated-page-with-HTTPWebRe (I tweaked it a bit) to write an application to do this.