# Failed to retrive session value when called the page using WebRequest.Create(URL)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I have a page (email.aspx) which is retrieving a session value and do some processing depends on that value.

When I call email.ASPX directly from the browser using its URL everything works perfectly without any issues.

```
Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim emailaddress As String
        Dim x As String = ""
        x = Session("id")
        If x = "" Then
            emailaddress = "failed to get session"
        Else

            ' Do some staff here
        End If

        Response.Write(emailaddress)


    End Sub
```

But when I try to call (email.aspx) using WebRequest.Create(URL) from another ASPX page that included embedded vb.net code, I figure out that it is failed to retrieve the Session value which leads to an error!

```
Public Function getemailaddress() As String

        Dim sURL As String
        sURL = "http://sample/email.aspx"

        Dim wrGETURL As System.Net.WebRequest
        wrGETURL = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(sURL)


        Dim emailaddress As String
        Dim objStream As System.Net.HttpWebResponse
        objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse

        If objStream.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK Then
            Dim responseStream As System.IO.StreamReader
            responseStream = New System.IO.StreamReader(objStream.GetResponseStream())
            emailaddress = responseStream.ReadToEnd()
        End If
        objStream.Close()


        Return emailaddress

    End Function
```

I can't figure out the reason behind this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manitain session values during HttpWebRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065765/how-to-manitain-session-values-during-httpwebrequest)

Answer (score 0):

A client's session identifier is stored in a cookie. The `WebRequest` only stores its cookies for as long as the **current** request is alive, then it removes them. You need to create a "global" [**`CookieContainer`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass it to the web requests you make in order to share the cookies between different requests.

Depending on in how many different places you make requests, you might want to pass it as an argument to your function:

```
Public Function getemailaddress(ByVal Cookies As System.Net.CookieContainer) As String

    ...your code...

    'We need to cast wrGETURL to a HttpWebRequest.
    Dim wrGETURL As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
    wrGETURL = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(sURL), HttpWebRequest)

    'Set our cookie container.
    wrGETURL.CookieContainer = Cookies

    ...your code...

End Function
```

You need to use the same `CookieContainer` for every request that shall have the same session, so declare one in your code before making all requests:

```
Dim Cookies As New System.Net.CookieContainer

MakeRequest1(Cookies) 'Example request.
MakeRequest2(Cookies) 'Example request.

'Make the email request, passing our cookie container to it.
Dim Email As String = getemailaddress(Cookies)
```

Comment: Thank you @visual vincent, I tried that but it didn't work for me, still email.aspx is not retrieving the session value (stored in server side) when I call it from another function!

Comment: @HatemHusam : Please update your question with more code showing your other requests and how you use the cookie container.

Comment: This solved my issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065765/how-to-manitain-session-values-during-httpwebrequest) using server.excute. Thank you very much

Comment: @HatemHusam : Glad you found a solution! Please close your question as a duplicate using the `close` button located under your post.